# How do I use the amadeus-java SDK to test pricing and booking flights?

Tags: java, sdk, amadeus

I understand that the [amadeus-java SDK](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java) offers methods that simplify GET and POST calls to the Amadeus Self-Service API endpoint [Flight Offers Search](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search).

Is there a way to make POST calls to [Flight Offers Price](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-price) and [Flight Create Orders](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-create-orders) within the SDK?

If the SDK does not have methods for this, how would I retrieve the access token [I fetched via SDK](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/authorization) to make those calls explicitly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flight Offers Price and Flight Create Orders are about to be integrated into the Java SDK (PRs opened, a bit more work to do and you will be able to use them).

The other solution will be to use the methods `post` and `get` directly from our client like in the example below (that you can find the [README description](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java) of the Java SDK):

> You can make any arbitrary API call as well directly with the .get
>   method. Keep in mind, this returns a raw Resource
>
> ```
> Response response = amadeus.get("/v2/reference-data/urls/checkin-links", Params.with("airlineCode", "BA"));
> response.getResult();
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it to work with that code after replacing `Resource` with `Response` (maybe an API change).

Comment: You are totally right, sorry for the error. I fixed the answer and the README in the SDK